# How to debug a 400 Bad Request response caused by a marschalling error from JSON to Java object by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

When testing endpoints during development I sometimes get a 400 Bad Request response. A breakpoint in the controller is never reached, indicating that a problem occurred earlier in the stack, often (always?) when the request JSON is being marshaled to a Java object. However, nothing is being logged and stepping through the code is not possible as the controller is never reached.
The Bad Request response is almost always caused by a missing field or a field containing data of the wrong datatype. How can I get more feedback on why the Bad Request was returned by Spring?

Comment: Increase log level of Spring and Jackson code.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of ways to do it, the simplest is using built in class of Spring `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA: ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Then turn on debug level log in `application.properties` file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

For more information, pls refer to this [doc](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging)